# Copy Row from one table to another using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have created two tables on my page. I want that when a user clicks on a table row, the data of that row is copied to another table.

```
<div class="processor">
<table id="proctable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover">
        <td><span id="4770K"><a href="#">Intel Core i7 4770K 4TH GEN. 3.5GHZ 8MB CACHE MAX TURBO FREQUENCY 3.9GHZ</a></span></td>
        <td>$320</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover">
        <td><span id="4771"><a href="#">Intel Core i7 4771 4TH GEN. 3.5GHZ 8MB CACHE MAX TURBO FREQUENCY 3.9GHZ</a></span></td>
        <td>$290</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover">
        <td><span id="4770"><a href="#">Intel Core i7 4770 4TH GEN. 3.4GHZ 8MB CACHE MAX TURBO FREQUENCY 3.9GHZ</a></span></td>
        <td>$280</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover">
        <td><span id="4771"><a href="#">Intel Core i5 4670K 4TH GEN. 3.4GHZ 6MB CACHE MAX TURBO FREQUENCY 3.8GHZ</a></span></td>
        <td>$240</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<div id="aside">
    <table id="comptable">
        <tr class="header">
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have searched for any help I may find but could not get any specific answer.

Here is the link to the code on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jibranjb/LzgNd/#&togetherjs=fcgCI5QRn8

I am fairly new to Javascript and jQuery so please consider that.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? When do you need to copy? If you just want to copy this will work $("#proctable tr").clone().appendTo( $("#comptable") )

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/4qFgX/1/ for demo

Comment: Actually I am working on a web page where I need to show the details of the clicked item. The detail div contains an ADD TO LIST button. When that button is clicked, the item needs to be added to the other table.

Comment: Is there any way to store the row in a variable and then display the row in the other table when the button is clicked?

Comment: check my answer, I have provided Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you wanted exactly. But if you want to store the data you can store it using arrays. ( you can use any data structure, I am using them as they are simple)

Check the below code, I am using items array, to store the selected row. On clicking the `Add to List` button, the selected tr will be added to the array and it will be display in the respective table.

```
var items = [];

$(".addBtn").on("click", function() {
    var newTr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
    items.push(newTr);
    newTr.appendTo( $("#comptable") );

});
```

I have added the `Add to List` button, the updated html markup would be;

```
<td>
    <input class="addBtn" type="button" value="Add to List">
</td>
```

[Updated Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qFgX/4/)

Answer (score 0):

add this script ( using Jquery)

```
$('#proctable tr.hover').unbind('click').click(function(){
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#comptable');
    return false;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4qFgX/3/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest this:

```
$('#proctable tr.hover').click(function () {
 var x = $(this)[0].outerHTML
 $('#comptable').append(x);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this ?

```
$(function() { // when dom is ready

    $('#proctable tr.hover a').on('click', function(e) { // when you click on a link
        var row = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0); // you get the direct parent of the current clicked element
        $('#comptable').append(row); // you append this parent row in the other table
        e.preventDefault(); // your prevent the default link action
    });

});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/LzgNd/1/**

Comment: ?? why someone voting -1